# Get company completion without evaluation in ess

Tags: company-mode, completion, ess, r

Is it possible to do completion without evaluating the buffer in `ess-mode`/`R-mode` which uses `company-R-objects` and `company-R-args` as backends ? Backends like `company-jedi` can do completion without evaluating any statement of current buffer. Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't think anyone had written such a thing. RStudio has R code analysis, and in principle you could write elisp to use it as a backend for company. I don't know how hard it would be to separate the code analysis tools from RStudio-the-IDE

Comment: @Ista Each time I eval the buffer, the figures generate again. I know there are commands for evaluating paragraphs and defun, but remembering every step of last evaluation is so hard for me. I didn't known about that ess has no code analysis tool for it has such a long history.

Comment: If you have a specific question about getting useful completions from ESS I suggest asking in a new question.